# Url change but component will not change when we go back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components i.e. Project component and MainContainer. Maincontainer will fetch data again and again using fetchData method, so in this I am able to change the url as well as component when I move forward but during backward it will not change the component but url can change.

Project Component:

```
conditionalRendering(project) {
    let text;
    if (project.attributes.folder_id) {
      text = <Link to={`/folder/${project.attributes.folder_id}`}> 
                {project.attributes.name}</Link>
    } else {
      text = <span>{project.attributes.name}</span>
    }
    return text;
  }
```

MainContainer Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const paths = this.props.location.pathname.split('/')
    const id = paths[paths.length - 1]
    console.log('componentDidMount')

    axios.get(this.state.url, {
      params: {
        folder_id: id
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Axios response of componentdid mount')
      console.log(response)
      this.setState({
        isLoading: !this.state.isLoading,
        documents: response.data.data
      })
    })
  }

  fetchData(folder_id) {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    })
    console.log('updating state fetch data')

    axios.get(this.state.url, {
      params: {
        folder_id: folder_id
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Axios response inside fetchData')
      console.log(response)
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        documents: response.data.data,
      })
    })
  }

  selectRow(document) {
    this.setState({
      selectedRow: true,
      rowDetails: document
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    console.log('componentDidUpdate')

    if (prevState.isLoading === false) {
      console.log('if will run isLoading is false')
      this.setState({ isLoading: true })

      console.log('if will run isLoading is true' )

      const paths = this.props.location.pathname.split('/')
      const id = paths[paths.length - 1]

      axios.get(this.state.url, {
        params: {
          folder_id: id
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Axios response componentdidupdate')
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
          isLoading: !this.state.isLoading,
          documents: response.data.data
        })
      })
     }
    }

  documentsCollection() {
    let documentComponents;
    if (this.state.documents.length > 0 ) {
      documentComponents = this.state.documents.map(document => {
        return (
          <tr key={document.id} onClick={() => this.selectRow(document)}>
              <span className="file-thumbnail float-right"><i className={document.attributes.is_folder ? 'fas fa-folder' : 'far fa-file'}></i></span>
            <td data-label="Name">
              <Link to={`/folder/${document.attributes.id}`} onClick={() => this.fetchData(document.attributes.id)}>{document.attributes.filename}</Link>
          </tr>
        )
      })

      return documentComponents;
    }
  }
```

Router Component:

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component= {Project} />
      <Route path="/folder/:id" component= {MainContainer} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already in Maincontainer and only the id value has changed, componentDidMount will not be activated. Please use componentDidUpdate and compare props.